# Repository of TikZ shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf, repositories

Ti*k*Z shapes are extremely hard to create – even the documentation admits as much.

On the other hand, the selection of shapes that ships with the `tikz` package is pretty meagre – besides rectangles, circles, diamonds and regular polygons there isn’t much more. A split circle and a few strike outs is about all.

**Is there an online repository of ready usable high-quality shapes?**

For example, I’m searching for a [tag shape](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&q=tag+shape) and while this is of course straightforward to create myself<sup>1</sup> it’s still a lot of work and most probably redundant since someone else must have needed the same shape aready.

---

<sup>1</sup> I’ve already created a “document” shape with a dog ear in one corner based on the tutorial in the documentation. Including debugging and parameter tweaking, this has certainly taken me more than one hour.

Comment: If there isn't there should be! Perhaps suggest to the texample crowd...

Comment: I'm planning for some time to create a repository of small useful TikZ snippets where something like this would fit in, but I never get around to code a webpage for it...

Comment: I would be very interested to contribute to this open source initiative, if we agree to start it. One thing which will be very helpful is a collection of UML shapes.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your "document" shape example?

Comment: @Bart It’s on a computer that I haven’t touched in months. Next time I use this PC, I’ll try to remember copying it. But it’s not that well done anyway.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Don't bother if it's much of a hassle. I was trying to create a new shape using `foo/.style={...}`, but it seems composing a shape from >1 primitive is not possible this way, right?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: could you share the code of the document shape?

It would indeed be great if one could build a repository of default Tikz shapes... I published some shapes regarding digital electronics at https://github.com/KommuSoft/publications/blob/master/cursus_Digitale_Elektronica_en_Processoren/pgflibraryDEPcomponents.code.tex

Perhaps one could start a github repository where users can publish their own shapes

Comment: @CommuSoft Sorry I don’t have the shape document lying around at the moment. I’ll try to find it on my old laptop when I get home but I’m not sure I actually still have it.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know of a central repository, however, there are a lot of examples [at TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/nodes-and-shapes/)

Comment: I like this one: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/parameterised-pig/

Comment: but most of those aren’t new node shapes, just examples of the existing shapes. For example, the pig “shape” mentioned by @xport isn’t actually a node shape. It’s just a macro that *uses* a tikz picture. In fact, only *three* of those examples declare new shapes …